# Infinite loop because of setstate in build

Tags: flutter, dart

Here the address part is not working due to the set state in build sync can anyone help me with this code. I am stuck in an infinite loop.

[image]

Comment: You should use FutureBuilder or some other builder. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

Comment: Please do not post code as a image, [edit] your post and paste the code as text in